# How to implement frequency of attack in game?

Tags: frequency

In a RPG game,suppose there are role A and B.

A will conduct x attacks per second

B will conduct y attacks per second

If we suppose A initiates the attack and the final attacks may be :

> A A B A B ...

How to calculate the sequence of attacks?

Comment: Is this a concurrency question or do you just want to know how many attacks?

Comment: The goal is to get the entire sequence of attacks until one of them dies.

Comment: Could there be more than 2 roles in the same battle?

Comment: Is there a language you would prefer an example for? This could expressed elegantly with infinite lists and lazy evaluation, but such an answer would not be much use to you if you are using a language that can't naturally represent such data types.

Comment: Are your battles turn based or in continuous time? Perhaps it make more sense to say 'attacks per turn' instead of per second?

Comment: Could some characters have attack rates of less then 1 per second, for example only one attack every 2 seconds? I.e. frequency = 0.5 per second?

Comment: @Mark Byers,yes the rate can be arbitary real numbers.Only 2 players in 1 battle.

Comment: Would it also be relevant to return the time of each attack or is only the order of the attacks important? What it two attacks should occur simultaneously? Which should come first? Always A? First time A first, next time B first? Random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in Python 3.0 using a generator and fractions:

```
def get_attack_sequence(a, b):
    from fractions import Fraction
    count_a = count_b = 0
    rate_a = Fraction(1, a)
    rate_b = Fraction(1, b)
    while 1:
        new_count_a = count_a + rate_a
        new_count_b = count_b + rate_b

        if new_count_a < new_count_b:
           yield "A"
           count_a = new_count_a
        elif new_count_a > new_count_b:
           yield "B"
           count_b = new_count_b
        else:
           yield "A|B"
           count_a = new_count_a
           count_b = new_count_b

attack_sequence = get_attack_sequence(3, 2)
print(' '.join(next(attack_sequence) for _ in range(10)))
```

Output:

```
A B A A|B A B A A|B A B
```

An attack frequency of 0 needs to be checked for. I haven't done this in the above code for simplicity, but it's easy to fix and probably best handled outside this function (a battle where one player can't attack wouldn't be very interesting anyway).

An advantage of this idea is that it could be easily extended to more than 2 simultaneous players.

Another advantage is that it can also handle attack rates of less than one attack per second without any modification (e.g. B attacks only once every two seconds, i.e. attack frequency = 0.5).

Comment: What does the line after the third A mean? Simultaneous attack?

Comment: Yes,that's what it means.What's your opinion?

Comment: You've already accepted my answer, but I have a better suggestion now using rational numbers to get precise times for the simultaneous attacks. I'm going to update my answer even though you've already accepted it. If you prefer the old answer, let me know and I can change it back.

Answer (score 3):

Count who has more attacks. Call him MORE. Divide MORE/LESS and take floor, the result is = N. Then for every N attacks of MORE add one of LESS and pad with attacks of MORE when finished. That's each second.

Example:

```
MORE = 5
LESS = 2
MORE/LESS floor = 2

Then:
MORE MORE LESS MORE MORE LESS MORE
```

Another example:

```
MORE = 3
LESS = 2
MORE/LESS floor = 1

Then:
MORE LESS MORE LESS MORE
```

Comment: +1 I really like this solution too - simple and effective. After clarifying the question a bit more though, this doesn't quite meet all the requirements. Maybe it could be adapted to work though.